# Firebase silently fails in electron app

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, redux, electron

I am trying to use Firebase SDK in my Electron + React + Redux App.

so in my reducer I have these:

```
import firebase from 'firebase'

// Initialize Firebase
var config = {
    apiKey: "...",
    authDomain: "....firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://....firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "....appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "..."
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

...

case XYZ:

    firebase.database().ref().on("value", function(snapshot) {
        console.log("Hello World")
    })
```

The callback is never called. I tried placing this code in my componentDidMount callback, in my redux actions file, nothing works. And it fails silently, there are no errors in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lied in Firebase database rules. I had not authenticated the local session before attempting read/write operations.

so It was:

```
{
  "rules": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

I changed it to:

```
{
  "rules": {
      ".read": "auth == null",
      ".write": "auth == null"
  }
}
```

Which is probably not what most of the people want to do, instead authenticate the session using Firebase Auth and it will work.

But its annoying that the code doesn't throw any kind of error. Hard to debug.